# Remove duplicates conditionally in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove duplicates in an array in JavaScript. The given array being

`array = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]`

`resultant_array = [1,2,3,1,2]`

Here the second 1 is not considered as a duplicate

OR

`array = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`

`resultant_array = [1]`

any ideas how i can do this

Comment: [Lodash `uniq`](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniq)?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Remove duplicates if and only if they are consecutive? And what happened to `22`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: So you want to remove consecutive duplicates? `resultant_array = array.join(",").replace(/((?:^|,)([^,]+))(,\2(?=,|$))+/g,"$1").split(",");`

Comment: What happened to the `22` at the end? Is it a typo?

Comment: why not `resultant_array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 22]`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir That was a typo. Corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` like this:

```js
var array = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,22];

var result = array.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if(r[r.length - 1] != e) // if the last element in the result is not equal to this item, then push it (note: if r is empty then r[-1] will be undefined so the item will be pushed as any number is != undefined)
    r.push(e);
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [1,1,2,2,3,3];
var obj = {};
for(var i in arr) {
   obj[arr[i]] = true;
}
var result = [];
for(var i in obj) {
   result.push(i);
}
```

I set the keys of the object as the value of the array and there can't be multiple keys with the same value. Then I took all the keys and put it in the result.

Comment: this will give me [1,2,3] in all cases ...even if i pass [1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3].. I need [1,2,3,1,2,3] in that case

Comment: This may not have answered the OP's question but it certainly did answer mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could check the predecessor with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, , 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r[r.length - 1] === a ? r : r.concat(a);
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Or use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and an object for the last value.

```js
var array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, , 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    result = array.filter(function (a, i, aa) {
        return this.last !== a && (this.last = a, true);
    }, { last: undefined });
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. That 22 was a typo. I corrected it. Can you tell me how this works?

Comment: `concat` seems a bit ressource consuming as it's creating a new array every time!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, you could use filter ...